# Calling simple WCF service from jQuery - 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, json, wcf

During the last 4 hours i've been looking at any post I could find regarding this question, so I might be a little blind by now ;-)

I am trying to call a simple WCF service using jQuery. I've been using WebMethods for some time, and I am trying to migrate some. I am trying to test with the most simple webservice you can imagine:

```
[ServiceBehavior(IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true)]
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "")]
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public class ForumOperationService : IForumOperationService
{
    public string Horse(string prefixText, int count)
    {
        return "hestWCF";
    }
}
```

My jQuery call:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            var hest;
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                datatype: "application/json",
                url: "Services/ForumOperationService.svc/Horse",
                data: { prefixText: 'a', count: 10 },
                success: function (data) {
                    hest = data;
                }
            });
        });
```

My web.config is like this:

```
 <system.webServer>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior">
          <enableWebScript />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
    <services>
      <service name="ForumOperationService">
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior"
            binding="webHttpBinding" contract="IForumOperationService" />
      </service>
    </services>
    .... (more stuff)
```

In Firebug I get the following error:

> *NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error - 
>   `http://localhost:21599/Client/Services/ForumOperationService.svc/Horse`*

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**:

Just ran the WCF Test Client, and got this error:

> The service class of type ForumOperationService both defines a
>   ServiceContract and inherits a ServiceContract from type
>   IForumOperationService. Contract inheritance can only be used among
>   interface types. ÿIf a class is marked with ServiceContractAttribute,
>   it must be the only type in the hierarchy with
>   ServiceContractAttribute. ÿConsider moving the
>   ServiceContractAttribute on type IForumOperationService to a separate
>   interface that type IForumOperationService implements.

Will follow up tomorrow.

Comment: did you tried in WCFTestClient? also try to mark the method as [WebInvoke]. though your issue looks more like your its not hitting your service.

Comment: I just tried, and got updated the post :-) Thanks for the hint!

Comment: you welcome! If your method params easy enough, WCFTestClient is quick way to test out before start using it from application code.

Comment: Yup, that message made sense. Now I am dealing with another error. Please post using that client as an answer, then I will accept it. It is definetely a server error, and that tool will help most plp finding the error :)

Comment: Sure, I posted as answer. Whats another error you are getting?

Comment: That was some JSON specific things, but it all works now :-) Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test the method using WCFTestClient(.exe) and confirm that method is working fine, you will get actual error if not.

If your method params easy enough, WCFTestClient is quick way to test out before start using it from application code.